# SSH server accepts key ONLY if user is logged in (on server)

Tags: ssh

I can connect to my server using (id_rsa) key WHEN the local account **on the server** is logged in.

If I reboot server and leave it at the login manager,and then attempt to connect,  SSH returns

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

Permissions to /.ssh and .ssh/authorized keys are 700 and 600 respectively on both server and client.

Client:

```
henry@MSI-LT17:~ > ls -la ~ | grep ".ssh"
drwx------   3 henry henry  4096 Jan 23 16:31 .ssh
henry@MSI-LT17:~ > ls -la ~/.ssh | grep "authorized_keys"
-rw-------  1 henry henry  228 Jan 23 16:31 authorized_keys
```

Server:

```
henry@henry-dt:~ > ls -la ~ | grep ".ssh"                                                                                                                                               drwx------  2 henry henry    4096 Jan 19 18:24 .ssh
henry@henry-dt:~ > ls -la ~/.ssh | grep "authorized_keys"
-rw-------  1 henry henry  397 Jan 19 18:56 authorized_keys
```

Here is the -vvv output of the attempted login:

```
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/henry/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 0d:a8:df:84:1b:25:6e:7f:04:ad:98:87:bd:0b:7d:88
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/henry/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/henry/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/henry/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/henry/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/henry/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/henry/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I suspect the `debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker` has something to do with it...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer. Home folder was encrypted...

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Troubleshooting